# Restriction of sheaf on a closed subscheme is in general not quasi-coherent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In Hartshorne 5.2.4, we have

> If $Y$ is a closed subscheme of a scheme $X$, then the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X|Y}$ is not in general quasi-coherent in $Y$.

I'm having a hard time believing this, mainly because I can't think of any examples. Would any affine $X$ make an example? Say we have the closed subscheme $Y = \text{Spec } A/\mathfrak{a}$ embedded in $X = \text{Spec } A$.

Thanks!

Comment: As Hartshorne points out, it isn't even an $\mathcal O_Y$-module in general: $A$ is typically not an $A/\mathfrak a$-module

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$, and take $Y$ the closed point $(p)$. Thus $Y=\text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Then the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X|_Y=\mathcal{O}_{X,(p)}=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ since $Y$ is just a closed point. This is cannot be given a $\Gamma(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ module structure. 
More info can be found: [Concrete Example: Subsheaf is not Quasi-Coherent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666832/concrete-example-subsheaf-is-not-quasi-coherent)

However, I would be interested in seeing a more geometric example.